# How can i release delay in EZAudio?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, delay, ezaudio

I need to make some effects with audio file, using EZAudio. But this [method](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio#chaining-audio-unit-effects) not work. What do i need to add in this code? How can i use delay to my audio?

Comment: i tried to do like this [_player setOutput:CFBridgingRelease(_delayNodeInfo)]; But it is not work. And get total error...